# 301 with special characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have searched stackoverflow for an answer to this pesky 404 that I can't redirect for some reason.

This is the link that I want to redirect:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/product&manufacturer_id=14&page=4`

And I want to redirect it to:

`www.example.com`

This is how I enter it into my htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/manufacturer/product&manufacturer_id=14&page=4$
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
```

I have redirected other links with the `?` (question mark) using `%{QUERY_STRING}`, but this one just won't work.

So I need a little help with this one.

Comment: Your rule looks fine, are you sure some other rule isn't getting applied first?

Comment: Nice to know it looks fine, not so nice that it's not working.  =)
I have tried placeing it directly after

RewriteBase /


So it should be the first rule to kick in...

Comment: Is this rule placed in root .htaccess? Are you using any CMS/PHP framework?

Comment: Yes, its placed in the root .htaccess
Not 100% sure what to answer to teh CMS/PHP question, but the site is an Opencart webshop.

So I think you can say yes to both CMS/PHP framework.

Comment: Bump*

Anyone with any suggestion at all?